# PNG is exporting with white background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

[image]I am trying to export a PSD image to PNG with a transparent background. No matter what I do it is not working.

[image]

I do not understand what/where the problem is. I tried using Illustrator too, but it still exported with a white background. Transparency was checked every time in both applications.

Comment: Discussion on accepting answers has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108223/discussion-on-question-by-suraiya-abedin-png-is-coming-with-white-background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the other answers, no export setting can create transparency where there is none. You can, however, use a quick trick to remove a white background form an image like this is using `Blend If`:

1. Open your image in Photoshop.
2. Make sure the image is a single, regular layer, not a background layer. If it is a background layer, double-click its bar in the Layers palette and choose 'OK' to make it into a regular layer.
3. Double-click the layer's bar in the Layers palette again so the 'Layer Styles' window appears.
4. At the bottom of that window, find the 'Blend If' settings. The Setting after the words 'Blend If' should be set to 'Gray'.
5. Focus on the top bar, that says 'This Layer' and find the gray arrow at the right end of the bar.
6. Press and hold <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd> and drag the left *half* of that arrow slightly to the left. In your example image, I got nice results with a value around 220.
7. Click 'OK'.
8. Export as a .png as you are used to, ensuring to check the 'transparency' box.

Comment: .. amazing!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The checkbox will not magically transform a white background into a transparent one.

In the screen capture, you posted the background is clearly white. If it were transparent you would see the gray checkerboard.

See if you have a white layer that needs to be turned off before exporting, or create a mask.

Comment: I downloaded a PSD file and tried to convert it to PNG. I didn't put any white background,  seeing no other way I converted the PSD into JPEG. and tried to convert it into PNG. all failed.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin, could you take a screenshot of the document + the layers panel? The point here is that as far as we know based on the tiny bit of the document we can see below the window, there appears to be a white background. Just saving it as a png isn't going to magically make the white background disappear.

Comment: added. kindly check @Joonas

Comment: photoshop is very new to me. but I have downloaded files converted into PNG. but I don't know why it is not working this time.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin, yea, looking at the layers panel, your image layer definitely has a white background. Your have to remove the background somewhat manually and then save it as a png. Or... Is this the way the document was when you first opened it or have you made changes? Or is there another file format you could've downloaded instead? It's not super hard to remove this background but for a beginner of your level, you might struggle with it. Youtube is full of background removal tutorials if you're up for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe your last comment made me see what is going on here. that white background is the basic part like all those petals is... so it won't disappear, I have to make it go away...

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin yes. You gotta tell it which parts you want to be transparent and then the png format simply retains the transparency. There are so many ways to remove a background that I'd suggest you include white background in the search terms. Something like: "Photoshop how to remove white background" or "Photoshop white background removal tutorial". You put that in the youtube search and you should find something good.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop you will see that images are transparent if the background is marked as a cheqerboard.

Example borrowed from Photoshop templates:
[image: Photoshop example file - non transparent and transparent image]

Here you can see the non-transparent on the left, and a transparent on the right.
If the PSD file you downloaded have layers, you might me able to "make it transparent" by disabling the (white) background layer before exporting to PNG. Access the layers from Window -> Layers.

Comment: so if the PSD has white background attached then it won't work? this picture has white background attached.

Comment: If the background is on a seperate layer you could hide that layer. If the image is flattened, you would have to remove it manually before exporting. Should be fairly easy to do with "magic wand" or "select color" on your image above.

Comment: Thank you. didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you've created a new document as artboard. Try to create a new one that's not an artboard.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113399)